# VConsole Setup fails: Virtual console /dev/tty0 is not in K_XLATE or K_UNICODE

Tags: systemd, tty, console

Since a few days journalctl shows the following error while booting:

```
systemd-vconsole-setup[701]: Virtual console /dev/tty0 is not in K_XLATE or K_UNICODE.
```

After that systemd-vconsole-setup fails to start. Does anybody know how to solve the problem and get rid of this error?

Comment: Did you travel forwards in time and use this? : https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Fedora-29-Flicker-Free-Boot Seriously, I think it's because you're using a graphical boot splash like `plymouth`.  When the Linux console is in graphics mode, it refuses to let you set the text console font.  To the best of my knowledge it's a kernel limitation and a big mess.  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/vt/vt.c#L4113  Unless someone hacks hooks into plymouth and elsewhere to setup the configured font when switching back to text mode...

Comment: Even more seriously, please always specify what distribution you are using, and your software version. It *might* have been due to some `plymouth` package update.